# How to get selected index in user control of dropdownlist from C# file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me. As i am not getting the selected index from the c# file in the user control

Comment: Or forward me some demo link.

Comment: How bad. However our crystal balls are cloudy today, you need to post some code to show how you did to give us some clue. You might want to read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please provide some code to describe the **problem in detail**. Furthermore you may have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section to generally improve your question.

Comment: post the code what are you doing to get the clear idea please.

Comment: I am not aware how to post the code. Please tell me

Comment: click on edit your post, paste your code and then you will see two curly braces above the text area , select the code and click on two curly braces icon above the text area. Tried my best to tell you about how to post if any mistake i apologise for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
MyUserControl.ItsDropdown.SelectedIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose that as property from your user control or you need to use find control to get the selected index of the dropdown which is part of user control.

In usercontrol codebehind file

```
public int drpSlctedIndex
{
  get 
  {
    return dropdownid.SelectedIndex;
  }
}
```

or

in the codebehind file of the aspx page where usercontrol used

```
int index = (usercontrolid.FindControl("dropdownid") as DropDownList).SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: Actually i am creating a time picker where i have take three dropdownlist for hour, min and period.So whatever the set in the aspx page, i need to access that in the user control and get that value back in my webpage. But any index selected in my webpage, i am getting -1 as index in usercontrol.

Comment: @user958802 - you can use one fo the above two technique ..that will resolve your issue..

Answer (score 1):

```
//ASPX page
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //accessing the SelectedIndex
      int dl= ((DropDownList)this.userControlName.FindControl("DropDownList1")).SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

or any where you want to access the **index**.

Here is the code for TimerUserControl and Aspx page. I tried my best to explain to you what I have understood. Hope this will help.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TimeUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TimeUserControl" %>
hour:<asp:DropDownList ID="hour" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
Minute:<asp:DropDownList ID="Minute" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
Seconds:<asp:DropDownList ID="Seconds" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind of TimerUserControl

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TimeUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public string SelectedTime
    {
        get
        {
            string _time = this.hour.SelectedItem.Text + ":" + this.Minute.SelectedItem.Text + " " + this.Seconds.SelectedItem.Text;
            return _time;
        }
    }

}
```

**Code Behind of Aspx Page:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
//ASPX page
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     // Accessing on Page Load with AutoPostBack Property to True for DropDownLists.
    //Every time you select any value from DropDownList the Page will Post back and Selected 
   // value will be in Response.
        string selectedtime = this.TimerUserControl.SelectedTime;
     Response.Write("Time----->" + selectedtime);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //accessing the selected time property if the SelectedTime(Public) property is in User control 
        // Here you wont require to set the AutoPostBack Property  to true for DropDownLists.

        string selectedtime = this.TimerUserControl.SelectedTime;

        Response.Write("Time----->" + selectedtime);
    }



}
```

Comment: Actually i am creating a time picker where i have take three dropdownlist for hour, min and period.

Comment: So whatever the set in the aspx page, i need to access that in the user control and get that value back in my webpage. But any index selected in my webpage, i am getting -1 as index in usercontrol

Comment: right you can use above code for all three (separate) to get either selected index or selected text for each dropdown list

Comment: You need set the AutoPostBack Property to true for dropdown lists

Comment: But the problem if i make the AutoPostBack Property to true.... it will again rebind the dropdown items in the usercontrol.

Comment: public string SelectedTime
        {
            get
            {
                string _time = dphour.SelectedItem.Text + ":" + dpMinute.SelectedItem.Text + " " + dpPeriods.SelectedItem.Text;
                return _time;
            }
        }

Comment: is this property is in User Control or on ASPX Page, i think it will be on UserControl side isnt it?

Comment: Thank you very much but i am using web user control..ie .cs file. I have acheived in this way.